# My android app crashed on startup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

I have followed [this](http://youtu.be/QRa4yMjoI7c) for making my app. When I run it on my android 2.1, the app gets stuck. Can you help me? What can I do to make my app working?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://check.be?v=1";
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <webView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="be.moviechecker.bioscoopprogramma"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name="be.moviechecker.bioscoopprogramma.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Is Logcat saying anything usefull?

Comment: try running the app on an AVD first and post the logcat information

Comment: Do you really have `webView` in the widget name in your xml file? If yes, please check if it works with WebView? And check the error message in logcat.

Comment: "the app gets stuck" - what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Add the logcat output to your question...

Comment: `<webView` is it a typo ? It should be `<WebView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity_main.xml file you've used 'webView' instead of using 'WebView' hence it is not getting recognized. Please change it to to WebView and check the result. It will work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But wen i click on a link my browser will pop up, how can i make all the links witout "http://" will open in the webview?

Answer (score 0):

@user3142817. Welcome. I've made below code make it work for you. Please check

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView view;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        view.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) 
            {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
               return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && view.canGoBack()){
            view.canGoBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```